# SAS RAID controller or SATA for typical Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-rec, hardware-raid, sas

I purchased an HP Z620 recently.  It came with one Xeon CPU, 32GB of RAM, and an LSI SAS 9212-4i controller.  I'm planning to install Windows 10 on a typical SSD drive (non-NVMe).

This machine has 6 SATA ports (2 @ 6Gb/s and 4 @ 3Gb/s) on the mainboard.  I assume the previous user needed something more, hence the extra LSI controller.  And from what I can see, the previous configuration was that the hard drives were all connected to the LSI card and not the ports on the motherboard.

I have limited understanding of SAS and RAID, so basically I'm wondering what's the best way for me to install Windows 10 ?  Attach my SSD to one of the LSI ports, or on the 6Gb/s SATA on the mainboard ?

I have no plans to set up any sort of RAID on this machine, just want the best configuration possible in terms of speed, using a single SSD drive for the OS.  Is the LSI card overkill, should I just remove it ?

Comment: its not uncommon to put the OS and the data on different controllers. additionally it sounds like the SATA controller (w/ only 2 Sata3 ports) would be insufficient for array types that require 3+ disks like Raid5. generally a system configured like this would use Raid1 on SATA (presumably for the local OS) and either use an expansion card or SAN connection for additional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The RAID controller will have extra cache that can provide a bit of a speed boost for writes, but only if you have the CacheVault option that protects the cache contents on power loss.

Without the option, it's not worth it for a single drive.